# What can I use instead of redirectURL?

Tags: javascript

Can someone help me with this?

I created a html script with javascript for a touchscreen with the function onclick to do 3 things when hitting a touchscreen button:

1. show a touched button
2. sending a preset to the camera
3. preview the camera in vMix.

   http://192.168.1.10/command/visca-inquiry.cgi?visca=8101043F0205FF','http://192.168.1.215:8088/api/?Function=PreviewInput&Input=1','camcontrol1.html')">CAM1 
    Preset A

This is the (externall) javascript file:

```
function TripleRedirect(redirectURL1,redirectURL2,redirectURL3) {top.frames['TargetFrame1'].location.href = redirectURL1;top.frames['TargetFrame2'].location.href = redirectURL2;top.frames['CamControlFrame'].location.href = redirectURL3;}
```

This is working perfect when the computer (i3 Win7) only runs the script, but when I also receive a stream from youtube
very often the camera preset and preview are not executed.
The touchscreen is working OK because the button is showed every time as a touched button.

Sometimes I have to hit the button 5 times before it is sending the commands to the camera and vMix.

It seems the onclick command is not executed, but why?
The computer has gigabit network, so it shouldn't be a network bandwidth problem.
Is there maybe a better way to to 3 things with onclick?

(the script is running in FF and the youtube stream in Chrome)

Comment: Don't tell me that i3 there means core i3.